# react native dropdown how to specify different color/style for each label?

Tags: react-native, react-native-element-dropdown

I want to apply different colors/font sizes for each of the labels in the drop-down. I may add the style to the data array like data=[  { label: 'Tt', value: '10',{fontColor:'red'}},...]. Any suggestions on this?

```
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
const data = [
                    { label: 'Tt', value: '10'},
                    { label: 'Tt', value: '12' },
                    { label: 'Tt', value: '16' },
                    { label: 'Tt', value: '20' },
                    ];



   const DropdownComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

    const renderLabel = () => {
      if (value || isFocus) {
        return (
          <Text style={[styles.label, isFocus && { color: 'blue' }]}>
                    </Text>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };

    return (
      <View style={stylesDropDown.container}>
        {renderLabel()}
        <Dropdown
          style={[stylesDropDown.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: 'blue' },  ]}
          placeholderStyle={stylesDropDown.placeholderStyle}
          selectedTextStyle={stylesDropDown.selectedTextStyle}
          // inputSearchStyle={stylesDropDown.inputSearchStyle}
          iconStyle={stylesDropDown.iconStyle}
          data={data}
          // search
          maxHeight={300}
          labelField="label"
          valueField="value"
          itemTextStyle="style"
          placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select item' : '...'}
          searchPlaceholder="Search..."
          value={value}
          onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
          onChange={item => {
            setValue(item.value);
            setIsFocus(false);

          }}
          renderLeftIcon={() => (
            // <AntDesign
            //   style={styles.icon}
            //   color={isFocus ? 'blue' : 'black'}
            //   name="Safety"
            //   size={20}
            // />
             <><Text>T</Text><Text>t</Text></>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply different colors or font sizes to each label in the dropdown, you can modify the data array(you can change this data array dynamically also) by adding a FontColor and FontSize property to each item.

```js
const data = [
  { label: 'Tt', value: '10', fontColor: 'red', fontSize: 14 },
  { label: 'Tt', value: '12', fontColor: 'green', fontSize: 16 },
  { label: 'Tt', value: '16', fontColor: 'blue', fontSize: 18 },
  { label: 'Tt', value: '20', fontColor: 'purple', fontSize: 20 },
];
```

Declare a function named **renderLabelStyle** ,

```js
  const renderLabelStyle = (label) => {
    const item = data.find((item) => item.label === label);
    if (item) {
      return {
        color: item.fontColor,
        fontSize: item.fontSize,
      };
    }
    return null;
  };
```

After that you need to change the **itemTextStyle** in your Dropdown component like this,

```js
itemTextStyle={(label) => renderLabelStyle(label)}
```

Try using this .

Comment: thanks for the answer, didn't work though.

Comment: Type '(value: any) => { fontSize: any; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.ts(2322)